# F# - Function not returning updated data

Tags: function, dictionary, f#, immutability, mutable

I have a function GetCars which does not return the updated state. If I add a parameter, it works fine, or if I execute the same code in the other functions it works fine.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Concurrent

type Car = {
    Make : string
    Model : string
    ID : int
}

type Cars = {
    Count : int
    Collection : Car[]
}

module AppState = begin
    let state = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, obj>()

    let added = state.TryAdd("cars", {
        Count = 1
        Collection = [| { Make = "Honda"; Model = "Civic"; ID = 0 } |]
    })

    let DownCastCars (o : obj) =
        match o with
        | :? Cars as cars -> Some(cars)
        | _ -> None

    let GetCars = 
        let mutable cars : obj = null; 
        let success = state.TryGetValue("cars", &cars)
        if success then
            DownCastCars cars
        else
            None

    let AddCar car =
        match GetCars with
        | Some cars -> 
            state.TryUpdate("cars", { cars with Collection = Array.append cars.Collection [| car |] }, cars)
        | None ->
            false
end

let AddCarMakeModel make model =
    let car : Car = {
        Make = make
        Model = model
        ID = match AppState.GetCars with
                | Some cars -> cars.Collection.Length
                | None -> 0
    }
    let success = AppState.AddCar car
    if success then
        printfn "Successfully added car :)"
    else
        printfn "Failed to add car :("

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    AddCarMakeModel "Honda" "Civic"
    AddCarMakeModel "Honda" "Civic LX"
    printfn "Press any key to continue"
    let s = Console.ReadLine()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

If I add a parameter to GetCars i.e

```
let GetCars notused = 
    let mutable cars : obj = null; 
    let success = state.TryGetValue("cars", &cars)
    if success then
        DownCastCars cars
    else
        None
```

Then the GetCars function will return the newest value every time. Or if I just place the same code inside the other methods I am using i.e

```
let AddCarMakeModel Make Model =
    let car : Car = {
        Make = make
        Model = model
        ID = match AppState.GetCars with
                | Some cars -> cars.Collection.Length
                | None -> 0
    }
    let success = AppState.AddCar car
    if success then
        printfn "Successfully added car :)"
    else
        printfn "Failed to add car :("
```

I am guessing this has to do with "Do Bindings" but I am not sure how to apply that successfully to GetCars. I did notice GetCars get called when the application starts, and if I set a break point inside the function it never gets that far again.

Comment: I believe you have to declare `GetCars` as `let GetCars () =`and modify the call site to be `GetCars()`, otherwise F# treats it as a (constant) value rather than a function that will be evaluated every time.

Comment: @mikez is correct - in f# anything that looks like `let a = ...` is a constant, not a function.  Some magic goes on and ensures that the code does actually run but it only runs once.  There will be a duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, the solution is to add a unit parameter.

The problem is that you are declaring a constant value, not a function value.

This is evident if you look at its signature: `val GetCars : Cars option` There is no arrow, just a value, so `GetCars` will be executed only once and bound to the value on the right side of the expression.

By adding a unit parameter you get the signature: `val GetCars : unit -> Cars option` so now at the call site you can refer either to the function value by `GetCars` alone or to execute it and get its result by `GetCars()`.

Also note you don't need the mutable since F# treat functions returning a value and a ref as a tuple, you can write `GetCars` like this:

```
let GetCars() = 
    match state.TryGetValue("cars") with
    | true, (:? Cars as cars) -> Some cars
    | _ -> None
```

And then get rid of the function `DownCastCars`.